# How to generate dynamic data table through api call in vuetify in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, datatables, axios, vuetify.js

I am trying to generate dynamic data table through Vuetify ,in vuejs but dont see any example in vuetify official documentation,does anyone mind sharing an example

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2):

By "dynamic" I'm guessing you mean data loads asynchronously from an API. The [Vuetify docs have numerous examples of data tables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/) including [one that simulates requesting data from an API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#paginate-and-sort-server-side). A very basic implementation looks something like (note: this example uses [the random user generator API](https://randomuser.me/):

```html
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="people"
    item-key="login.uuid"
    :loading="loading"
    :options.sync="options"
    :server-items-length="totalPeople"
    @pagination="updatePage"
    @update:options="customSort"
  ></v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  data: () => ({
    apiURL: 'https://randomuser.me/api/',
    headers: [
      { text: 'Name',     value: 'name', align: 'start' },
      { text: 'Country',  value: 'country' },
      { text: 'DOB (Age)',      value: 'dob' },
      { text: 'Contacts', value: 'contacts' },
    ],
    loading: false,
    options: {
      page: 1,
      itemsPerPage: 10,
      sortBy: ['name'],
      sortDesc: [true],
    },
    people: [],
  }),
  mounted () {
    this.getPeople()
  },
  methods: {
    async getPeople (page = 1, results = 10, seed = 'example') {
      this.loading = true
      const params = { params: { page, results, seed } }
      try {
        this.people = (await axios.get(this.apiURL, params)).data.results
        this.loading = false
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        this.loading = false
      }
    },
    updatePage (pagination) {
      const { itemsPerPage: results, page } = pagination
      this.pagination = pagination
      this.getPeople({ page, results })
    },
    customSort (options) {
      // The Random User API does NOT support sorting, but if it did, you
      // would need to make an API call that returned a sorted
      // list of results based on the sort parameter(s)
      console.log(options)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

For a more complex example that uses more of Vuetify's features, [check out this codepen](https://codepen.io/morphatic/pen/qBOrWGE).